# Regular Expression to capture strings between given string anchors

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file I'm trying to parse with regex (python). Each line contains tags "BEGIN" and "END" somewhere on the line. In addition, a line may contain one or more "VALUE" tags somewhere between the "BEGIN" and "END" tags. If there is no "VALUE" tag on a given line, I would like to capture the string between "BEGIN" and "END" tags. However, if there is a "VALUE" tag on a given line, I would like to capture all the strings between tags "BEGIN"..."VALUE", "VALUE"..."VALUE", and "VALUE"..."END" tag pairs. Note that a capture string may also be empty.

Given input:

```
Line1: words we can ignoreBEGINvalue1VALUEvalue with spaceVALUEvalue_with_@VALUElastvalueENDwords we can ignore
Line2: BEGINvalue1VALUEVALUEVALUElastvalueENDwords we can ignore
Line3: words we can ignoreBEGINlastvalueEND
```

Regex should return:

```
Line1: (1)value1 (2)value with space (3)value_with_@ (4)lastvalue
Line2: (1)value1 (2) (3) (4)lastvalue
Line3: (1)lastvalue
```

The below regex fails if there's more than one "VALUE" tag on a line, in which case it seems to capture only the strings between "BEGIN"..."VALUE" and "VALUE"..."END", but fails to capture the "VALUE"..."VALUE" matches:

```
BEGIN(.*?)(?:VALUE(.*?))*END
```

Comment: This would only work with PyPi regex module. See a better alternative below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach without full use of regex, catch everything between BEGIN and END and then split it with VALUE.

```
>>>test_cases = ['words we can ignoreBEGINvalue1VALUEvalue with spaceVALUEvalue_with_@VALUElastvalueENDwords we can ignore', 'BEGINvalue1VALUEVALUEVALUElastvalueENDwords we can ignore', 'words we can ignoreBEGINlastvalueEND']
>>> patt = re.compile(r'BEGIN(.*)END')
>>> for test in test_cases:
...     matched = patt.search(test)
...     if matched is not None:
...         print matched.group(1).split('VALUE')

['value1', 'value with space', 'value_with_@', 'lastvalue']
['value1', '', '', 'lastvalue']
['lastvalue']
```

Comment: I believe `r'BEGIN(.*?)END'` is better in case there are more than 1 begin-end pair on a line.